# Why do basic Ansible loops appear to make multiple ssh connections per item and host?

Tags: loops, ansible

Very beginner question, but trying to understand what's going on with loops vs not using loops. (ansible 2.9.9)

Here's my setup

```
# setup_servers.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - baseline

# staging.yml
---
all:
  children:
    hosts:
      host1:
      host2:
      host3:

# baseline/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: Create Users Task
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ developers }}"

# baseline/vars/main.yml
---
developers:
  - bob
  - jane
  - sally
```

And I when I run this: `ansible-playbook -i staging.yml setup_servers.yml` I get the following:

```
TASK [baseline : Create Users Task] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=bob)
ok: [host2] => (item=bob)
ok: [host3] => (item=bob)
ok: [host1] => (item=jane)
ok: [host2] => (item=jane)
ok: [host3] => (item=jane)
ok: [host1] => (item=sally)
ok: [host2] => (item=sally)
ok: [host3] => (item=sally)
```

However, if I don't use a loop in the task:

```
---
- name: Create Users Task
  user:
    name: "bob"
    state: present
  user:
    name: "jane"
    state: present
  user:
    name: "sally"
    state: present
```

I get this different output:

```
TASK [baseline : Create Users Task] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]
ok: [host3]
```

The way the output is shown it *appears* that in the looping case above it connects to each host separately for each item in the loop. Whereas with the non-looping task, it shows that it connects to each host just once. Also, the looping case takes quite a bit longer to complete (8x  longer - basic check with `time` prepended to the command for a couple of runs of each).

Is the output not indicative of the actual ssh behavior? Any insight into what's happening here would be helpful. If the looping scenario IS connecting once for each host AND item, is there a way to set this up so it connects to each host once and then loops through creating the users?

After re-reading all the docs on loops and many google searches I have not found an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your non-looping task is invalid.  You have three `user` calls, but only the last is actually executed.  YAML is **not** a programming language.  The YAML processing overwrites earlier items in a list that have the same key.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Can you give an example of a valid way to add multiple users without looping?

Comment: No.  But what's the problem with the loop?